# Client server javascript communication

Tags: javascript, html, api

I want to create 2 scripts, 1 for client 1 for server side.

I found snippet which allows call asyncrhonously js

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

(function() { 
    var projectId = "script";
    var protocol = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 
    'https://' : 'http://');
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.async = true;
    scriptTag.src = protocol + 'localhost/wp/' + 
    projectId + '.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptTag, s);
})();
function optimizelyTimeout() {
    window.optimizely = window.optimizely|| [];
    if (!window.optimizely.data) {
    window.optimizely.push("timeout");
    }
}
setTimeout(optimizelyTimeout, 1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This produces below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://localhost/wp/script.js"></script>
```

Now I would like script.js to return some custom js code which will be injected into original webpage. I tried with:
-return("code");
-response.write("code");

but non of that worked for me.

1. How script.js should look like in order to return some custom js code to be executed on client side?
2. How can I pass arguments from client to server side call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How script.js should look like in order to return some custom js code
>   to be executed on client side?

if the javascript code returned by script tag has to be invoked immediately then you need to return a self invoking function

```
(function(){ 
    /* code that you want to invoke immediately after the script has been loaded*/
})(this);
```

> How can I pass arguments from client to server side call?

just push the parameters in the script `src` itself

```
scriptTag.src = protocol + 'localhost/wp/' + projectId + '.js?param1=value';
```

and intercept the same on your server side